# Create events object after some data was

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events, child-process, eventemitter

I've several events which I need to listen to with additional event and pass object:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  myObj.data = true
  //here I need to raise the event with the property data
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  myObj.close = true
  //here I need to raise the event with the property close
});
```

For example inside of every event I want to emit **my events** and send object with property. For example raise myEvent with my object and every following event will update property in my object like data,close,open

Let's say this is my object

```
var myObj ={
  open:true,
  data:false,
  close:true
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious way is to code your own small event emitter/listener.

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

var eventer = {
    events: {},
    on: function(event, callback){
       if(!(typeof callback === 'function'){
           return;
       }
       if(!this.events[event]){
           this.events[event] = [];
       }
       this.events[event].push(callback);
   },
   trigger: function(event, data){
       if(!this.events[event]){
           this.events[event] = [];
       }
       this.events[event].forEach(function(callback){
           callback(data);
       }
   }
}
var myObj = {
   open: true,
   data: false,
   close: true
}

ls.on('close', (code) => {
    myObj.close = true;
    eventer.trigger('data-changed', myObj);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    myObj.data = true;
    eventer.trigger('data-changed', myObj);
});

eventer.on('data-changed', (data) => {
     //action on close
});
```

**Edit**

Since you're on Node, you can use the EventEmitter, which works in a similar way:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const util = require('util');

function MyEmitter() {
    EventEmitter.call(this);
}
util.inherits(MyEmitter, EventEmitter);

const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();
ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    myObj.data = true;
    myEmitter.emit('data-changed', myObj);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Camille 1+! what should I require and can you give complite example with my context I want to use it ...(not sure what is ls and way to call to ls.on  and the myObj.on ,Thank you!

Comment: ls is from your exemple above: const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']); I don't know where you need to track the changes, if you can provide an exemple of what you're trying to do, I can add more exemples

Comment: Thanks ive 3 questions :) , when I try it I got error for the two close property it defined twice ,2.  there is a nice way to sperate events from the objects which mean the object will have only the boolean properties ... 3. do I need to require the event emiter of node ?

Comment: I've separated the two in my exemple. I didn't see you were on Node, so my exemple was in pure JS, so you don't need to import anything. I've added an exemple with the node event emitter.

Comment: HI Camille sorry for my delay in the response, so I need to use just the second option ?

Comment: Can you please provide a complite example since im facing erorrs like "TypeError: MyEmitter.emit is not a function" ...

Answer (score 0):

You can create Events using the [`Event` object/API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

**Create a custom event (copy/paste from linked source)**

```
var event = new Event('build');

// Listen for the event.
elem.addEventListener('build', function (e) { ... }, false);

// Dispatch the event.
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

You'll likely want to know about the next section of the docs too that let you add custom data to you events:

```
var event = new CustomEvent('build', { 'detail': elem.dataset.time });

function eventHandler(e) {
  console.log('The time is: ' + e.detail);
}
```

This should work in all modern browsers except IE11. If you look at the docs, there is a longer example showing the work-around for older browsers.

Comment: Thanks Matthew , but we still need to support IE11...any other clean way to do that?

Comment: @Mark I just edited the answer slightly. If you read the docs a little more, there is an example solution under the header "The old-fashioned way" that should work for all browsers.